# JQuery Datepicker not detecting onselect for custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to detect the select of a jquery datepicker. but it does not seem to work. It does not give any errors but does not execute the function.

HTML

```
<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker-tafeltje"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     onSelect: refreshOptions
  });
});
```

I have also tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){console.log('test')}
  });
});
```

But this does not log anything either!

> Seems it is a problem in mapping! Thank you all for the answers

Comment: Your code works fine in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xztoagcx/. Please add more detail about the code you're using

Answer (score 0):

You should use this::

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    afterAdjustDate: function(i,o,p){
       console.log('test');
    }
});
```

OR

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     onSelect: function(e) {
         console.log('test');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(e) {
             alert(e);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-xI/qyl9vpwWFOXz7+x/9WkG5j/SVnSw21viy8fWwbeE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker-tafeltje"></div>
```